# Fading does not work when the insets are zero

Tags: java, swing, transparency, paintcomponent, miglayout

```
 public class FadingLayer extends JPanel {

    public FadingLayer(JPanel panel) {
        // when set to "insets 0 0 0 0", shows the FadingPanel without fading.
        setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 1 0 0 0"));  
        add(panel,"dock center");
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) arg0;
        AlphaComposite alpha = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, opacity);
        graphics.setComposite(alpha);
        graphics.setColor(getBackground());
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

This is the panel on which I am putting some fading effects. The opacity is updated using the swing's Timer class. The problem is when all insets values are set to 0 timer works but I just see the final result without any fading effect. But if even one of the insets are set to some non-zero value I can see the fading effect. Whats wrong, please help?

**EDIT :** 
it is happening when the panel (which is added to the `FadingPanel`) acquires the complete area. That is when `FadingPanel` is set as-->

```
 setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

**OR**

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0 0 0 0"));
add(panel,"dock center");
```

Comment: you know that there is a fully opaque panel sitting right on top of the panel that you're trying to fade, right?

Comment: Didn't get you? You mean the panel which is added to the FadingPanel.
But if it is not Opaque then there is just a white panel after fading.

Comment: Sorry, got you, it's working. I didn't set the color as the panel's background. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user1329572 please post your comment as answer and let SagarDabas accept your answer..

Answer (score 3):

SagarDabas's answer is correct, I'd just like to make some little comments

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) arg0;
    AlphaComposite alpha = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, opacity);
    graphics.setComposite(alpha);
    graphics.setColor(getBackground());
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

You have to be really careful when manipulating the graphs context.  The above code will effect all the components painted after it (leaving the alpha composite applied)

A better approach would be to copy the graphics before you start.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) arg0.create();
    // paint as normal
    graphics.dispose();
}
```

Comment: But I want to fade every component inside this panel. And by copying and disposing the graphics would only fade the current panel.

Comment: But you don't know what will be painted after you.  If you want to effect all the child components, override `paint` and do the same thing there; copy the Graphics, apply the composite, call `super.paint()`, dispose of the Graphics